# Htaccess: Redirect and remove paths after

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to block access to our `/admin.php` page and anything related to `admin.php` (this isn't a folder in our file system, we're using a central `.htaccess` in root).

I'm able to do this with the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.123\.123$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.*)?admin\.php(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://oursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works, however, anything after `/admin.php` sticks in the URL after redirection and goes to 404 page. I just want it to redirect to home.

For example, this URL `https://example.com/admin.php?/cp/login&return=` redirects to `https://example.com/?/cp/login&return=`.

It just strips the admin part. I need it to strip everything.

Comment: "this isn't a folder in our file system" - not quite sure what you mean by that? What "folder"? Presumably `/admin.php` does exist?

Comment: From other answers i've read, people mention a directory pertaining to /admin/ and putting an htaccess in there with a deny all line. i'm sure im confusing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://oursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

This line would redirect back to itself - it wouldn't "strip the admin part"?! The `$1` backreference in the *substitution* would hold the value `admin.php` in your example (captured from the `(.*)` in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*). To redirect to the home page you would need to remove the `$1` backreference.

The remaining part of the URL in your example (which is everything after the `?`) is the *query string*. By default this is indeed passed on to the *substitution* (target URL) unaltered. You need the `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag on Apache 2.4+. Or append a `?` on to the end of the *substitution* string in Apache 2.2  (effectively creating an empty query string).

You also don't need the *condition* that chacks against `THE_REQUEST` server variable, as this can be done (more efficiently) in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. (I assume you are not internally rewriting to `admin.php`?)

So, bringing this together we have:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.123\.123$
RewriteRule admin\.php / [QSD,R=302,L]
```

This checks for "admin.php" occurring anywhere in the URL-path of the requested URL.

You don't *need* to explicitly state an absolute URL in the *substitution* if you are redirecting back to the same host.

Note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect. Only change to a 301 (permanent) - if that is the intention - when you have confirmed it is working OK. 301s are cached hard by the browser so can make testing problematic.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: works exactly how I wanted, thank you very much. You've helped me understand .htaccess files much better as well.